# Issues with twilio integration with ZOHO CRM

Tags: twilio

Zoho CRM sending texts through Twilio to the leads mobile number when a task is created. The content is a reminder to finish the task,

I have hired 2 Zoho developers to integrate Twilio SMS to the Zoho CRM. It works fine when sending out mass SMS (except for the fact it will only do 50 at a time) however it randomly sends out messages to leads whenever a task reminder is made on the lead. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1d6LtscxTxMSwJR56pCfjdBNi1fNhZidGVT-TafIP4QE/edit?usp=sharing

I would like to be able to stop the random messages when tasks are created.

Comment: Did it resolve?

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with a rule that was created.

Try to find and then remove (or delete) that "**Workflow Rule**" that was created in "**Zoho Developer**" to "**Send SMS on Task**" functionality.

---

- Log in to Zoho Developer console and click Extensions for Zoho CRM.
- Select the extension you'd like to modify (Twilio) and click Edit.
- Click Automate in the left pane of the Extension Details page and click Workflow.
- Select the Rules tab at the top of the page.
- In the Workflow Rules page, click the Delete icon [] for the corresponding rule.

---

I'm not sure if you, or other developers you'll hire, need to know this but the rule was probably created following the instructions from https://www.zoho.com/developer/help/extensions/tutorials/twilio.html#link6